# Pattern Matching in Shell

Tags: shell, unix

My input text is in this format

```
 aa5b    r1     12715
 r2     12221
 aa43b   ew     13721
 eb     122331
 aa4b    ff     1055440
```

Output must be

```
aa5    r1     12715
r2    12221
aa43   ew     13721
eb  122331
aa4    ff     1055440
```

I tried with

```
 awk -F " " '{print $1}' t1 | grep "^aa*" > t2|sed s/b//g t2
```

The problem with this code is that the input text is not having a fixed pattern.

Comment: Do you want to zap the first b, or the last character if the first field, or the first character after a number, or something else? Your examples are too similar to infer how to generalize. Can you describe what you want with words? (All of these are "fixed patterns" in some sense, and yet you say there isn't one?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this version with `sed`?

```
sed 's/^\(aa[0-9]*\)b/\1/' t1 > t2
```

Comment: @Debaditya: Sorry - I don't understand your comment. I tried my solution with GNU sed 4.2.1, 4.1.5 and an old version within Solaris 8. For me it worked in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be easier to use something like perl and regex:

```
perl -p -e 's/^(aa[0-9]+)\w+/$1/' t1 > t2
```

Comment: perl -p -e 's/(.*?)b/$1/' t1 > t2 can also be used. It works well. I want it in shell.

Comment: @Debaditya What does "I want it in shell" mean?  In what way does using awk and grep satisfy your requirement that perl does not?

Comment: @William Using unix command. Perl can be used but it would be better if i get the result using unix commands(sed,awk,grep,find...)

Comment: Why is Perl less of a Unix command than Awk? Is this homework or why do you have this constraint?

Comment: @triplee There is no constraint at all. But I am learning sed and awk commands...In Perl i have the solution (perl -p -e 's/(.*?)b/$1/' t1 > t2) .I am still in the learning process.

Comment: FYI, perl comes out of the box with everything these days.  Even MacOS X.  and Solaris.  It *is* a unix command (at one point in the past it wasn't, but it very much is now).

Comment: Perl is less of a Unix command than awk, because awk is described in the Single Unix Specification, and perl isn't.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications are not clear from your description of the problem, but if you just want to delete all occurrences of the character 'b' on lines that begin 'aa', you can use:

```
sed '/^aa/s/b//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk ' $1 ~ /a/ { $1= substr($1,0,length($1)-1) };1' infile > outfile
```